# What is the Cafetière used for?

Tags: die2nite

What is the Cafetière (French for "Coffee machine") for?

I know that it requires loads of items to fix it; I'm just wondering what it does.

Comment: its actually called incomplete cafetiere if anyone cares for the in game name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It, uh, eventually makes coffee. Coffee restores 4 AP. It does not cause addiction and no limit on the AP/day it can restore.

> To make a cup of coffee, you need 1× Pharmaceutical Products, 1× Battery and 1× Rotten Log.
>
> <sub>[mordi2k](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/5521/mordi2k)</sub>

Comment: makes coffee as in, it used a water ration for that? or has no one ever fixed one?

Comment: @Andy Itching Plantations of Shadows had coffee. However, I didn't make it. All I know is it consumes drugs.

Comment: hmmm, converting drugs in a safe 4ap could be nice. hmmm, even if we wanted to fix it we missing the cyanide :P.

Comment: To make a cup of coffee, you will need 1x Pharmaceutical Products, 1x Battery and 1x Rotten Log.

Answer (score 3):

Just so there is a clear answer as an answer rather than in the comments of answer.

As mordi2k correctly stated in the comments, to create a "Bloody Hot Coffee" from the fixed Cafetière it requires 1 Battery, 1 Rotting Log and 1 Pharmaceutical Product.

The Bloody Hot Coffee is quite unique in that it does not count as a food, water or drug.  It replenishes 4 AP per cup and can be drank an unlimited number of times within one day with no change to your status, so a player could drink 100 coffee to invest 400 AP in construction on the same day and still have no negative status effects.

Answer (score -1):

Pros of coffee: unlimited use per day. If you had 100 coffee in the bank, you could spend 400AP all by yourself in one day.

Cons of coffee: trades a Pharmaceutical Product and a battery for a 4AP coffee.

Comment: ok, so i have 2 diffrent recipes for coffee now. water for a coffee or  1x Pharmaceutical Products, 1x Battery and 1x Rotten Log for a coffee.

Comment: Misleading, as it does not require a water ration, to make a cup of coffee. As I've stated in another comment here, "To make a cup of coffee, you will need 1x Pharmaceutical Products, 1x Battery and 1x Rotten Log. "